# how to limit numbers in json object to 2 digits after the decimal point

Tags: php, json, input, decimal

I am trying to store data from a form in a `.json` file. The input values are strings and i convert them to numbers:

```
$pooldata = [];
$pooldata['Free chlorine'] = floatval(round($_POST['fcl'], 3));
$pooldata['Total chlorine'] = floatval(round($_POST['tcl'], 3));
$pooldata['Combined chlorine'] = floatval( round($_POST['tcl'], 3) - round($_POST['fcl'], 3) );

$id = 'id_'.$pooldata['Date'];
$poolfile = 'data/'.$id.'.json';
$jsonData = json_encode($pooldata, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
file_put_contents($poolfile, $jsonData);

echo $pooldata['Free chlorine'].'<br />';
echo $pooldata['Total chlorine'].'<br />';
echo $pooldata['Combined chlorine'].'<br />';
```

The echo's gave me this ouput

```
1.65 // free chlorine
1.85 // total chlorine
0.2 // combined chlorine (= total chlorine - free chlorine)
```

but my json looks like this:

```
{
    "Free chlorine": 1.6499999999999999,
    "Total chlorine": 1.8500000000000001,
    "Combined chlorine": 0.20000000000000018
}
```

It should look like this:

```
{
    "Free chlorine": 1.65,
    "Total chlorine": 1.85,
    "Combined chlorine": 0.2
}
```

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: After `round()` something is already a number so `floatval()` serves no purpose. Note that `round()` can help you choose your type of rounding. For all intents and purposes `1.6499999999999999` is equivalent to `1.65`. Why do you want the latter?

Answer (score 1):

This looks an issue with `serialize_precision int`: [Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision)
This is determinded on the seerver

```
ini_set("precision", 14); 
ini_set("serialize_precision", -1);

$pooldata = [];
$pooldata['Free chlorine'] = floatval($_POST['fcl']);
$pooldata['Total chlorine'] = floatval($_POST['tcl']);
$pooldata['Combined chlorine'] = floatval($_POST['tcl'] - $_POST['fcl'])
```